# Length of line segment from point in circle to circumference

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Given a circle centered at $(0, 0)$ with known radius $r$, a point in the circle at $(a, b)$, and an angle $\theta$ (wrt the horizontal axis), is it possible to find the length of the line segment from $(a, b)$ to the circumference of the circle at angle $\theta$?

[image: diagram of problem]

My initial approach was to construct a scalene triangle using the radius, the line segment of interest, and a line segment from the origin to $(a, b)$. With that I would have 2 of the side lengths known, but I don't think it's enough information to solve using law of cosines. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Connecting center with segment ends $A=(a,b)$ and $B$ can give triangle with sides $OB=R$, $OA=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and angle $BAO=\arctan{\frac{b}{a}}-\theta$ for $b\geq 0$ or $BAO=\pi+\arctan{\frac{b}{a}}-\theta$. for $b<0$. Then one can use cosine rule to find $AB$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu this was my initial approach, but I'm unsure about you arrived at finding angle $BAO$.

Comment: I've mistaken. Then the simplest approach may be $(a+u \cos \theta)^2+(b+u\sin \theta)^2=R^2$ to find $u$ directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume that the angle $\theta$ is restricted to be in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, meaning that you always look to the right and up. Let $A(a,b)$ be the point you are given (and assume that $a^2+b^2<R^2$) and let $B,C$ be on the circle such that $B$ is on the line horizontal from $A$, so $B(\sqrt{R^2-b^2},b)$ (again assuming that you look to the right when doing the construction) and $C(\sqrt{R^2-x^2},x)$ is such that $\mu(\widehat{BAC})=\theta$.

Now this will get a little ugly with analytic geometry, but such is life.

We want to write the area of $\triangle ABC$ in two ways. This will give $\frac{AB\cdot AC \sin{\theta}}{2}=\frac{AB\cdot(x-b)}{2}$, where we used the sine area law on the LHS and the fact that the height corresponding to the edge $AB$ is just $x-h$ ($x>b$ as we assumed $\theta>0$). Simplifying this means $AC=\frac{x-b}{\sin{\theta}}$.

On the other hand, we can write down the length of $AC$. $AC^2=(\sqrt{R^2-x^2}-a)^2+(x-b)^2$, so we are left to solve the equation
\begin{equation*}
(\sqrt{R^2-x^2}-a)^2+(x-b)^2=\frac{(x-b)^2}{\sin^2{\theta}} 
\end{equation*}
or equivalently
\begin{equation*}
(\sqrt{R^2-x^2}-a)^2=\Big(\frac{(x-b)}{\tan{\theta}}\Big)^2.
\end{equation*}

Since we restricted $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, we can take square roots without worrying about signs, so we reduce to
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{R^2-x^2}=a+\frac{x-b}{\tan{\theta}}.
\end{equation*}

Squaring this should lead to degree two equation for $x$, and then we can get the length $AC$ as $\frac{x-b}{\sin{\theta}}$.

And if $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, one immediately sees that $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}=a$ and can solve this for $x$.

Comment: I got confused for a minute since $x$ is the $y$-coordinate of C. But it works out.

Comment: Ha, yeah. That's because I initially wanted to express the second coordinate in terms of the first, but then I realized that doing it that way I might need to care about signs as $b$  could be negative. So I had to swap, but I kept the x :)